# VisualVM Profile at JDK 1.7_21 crashes with "Access denied"

Tags: java, jvm

May be you can help me with this problem.

Profiler crashes with "Access denied" message, then i start it for any local application. In a logfile I found:

```
java.io.IOException: Отказано в доступе
    at sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.openProcess(Native Method)
    at sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.<init>(WindowsVirtualMachine.java:56)
    at sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(WindowsAttachProvider.java:69)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:213)
    at org.netbeans.modules.profiler.NetBeansProfiler.loadAgentIntoTargetJVM(NetBeansProfiler.java:762)
    at org.netbeans.modules.profiler.NetBeansProfiler.attachToApp(NetBeansProfiler.java:734)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiler.ApplicationProfilerView$MasterViewSupport.startProfiling(ApplicationProfilerView.java:309)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiler.ApplicationProfilerView$MasterViewSupport.access$900(ApplicationProfilerView.java:140)
    at com.sun.tools.visualvm.profiler.ApplicationProfilerView$MasterViewSupport$3.run(ApplicationProfilerView.java:262)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1372)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:1952)
```

Application runs on the same JVM HotSpot 1.07.0_21 x32 (VisualVM from JDK 1.6 works fine), using just next options:

```
-client -Xmx1524M
```

Any suggestions?

UPD: OS is WindowsXP sp3 x32

Comment: is the process you are trying to monitor running under the same user as the one running visualvm? if not then this is expected. to completly avoid this use JMX. emabling JMX in your app is some additional JVM options and you will be good to go

Comment: It's the same user. I already tried use jmx and it's only resolve problem with CPU Monitor and CPU Sampler, but has no effect on profiler.

Comment: is that a windows or linux machine?

Comment: It's WindowsXP sp3 x32

Comment: this might help you... http://www.first8.nl/profiling-remote-jvm-using-visualvm/ .. i had a similar issue running a iinux system.

Comment: thanks, but still not working

Comment: Some one had a [similar problem](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231078), but others can not reproduce it. Have you tried to upgrade NetBeans and JDK7 to latest version?

Comment: @Jifeng Zhang , I'm not an admin, so I left updating JDK as a last resort, if nothing else will help. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked their [troubleshooting section](http://visualvm.java.net/troubleshooting.html)?

in particular:

> Insufficient permissions for %TMP%\hsperfdata_username folder - make
>   sure you're able to create a file in the directory and eventually
>   update the permissions for full folder access. Alternatively you can
>   just re-create the folder which should automatically set the correct
>   access rights. See see this forums.sun.com thread for more details.

Comment: Even though I could create files, I still had to recreate the folder. First I tried deleting the files in the folder to see which applications were creating them, then when they were all gone I was able to remove and recreate the folder. I did it in an admin command prompt (Win key, type cmd, Ctrl+Shift+Enter).

Answer (score 0):

For me I got below error while creating the heap-dump:

```
[com.sun.tools.visualvm.attach.AttachModelImpl]: takeHeapDump java.io.IOException: Access is denied
```

I could manuallya access this folder `%TMP%\hsperfdata_username`. 
Hence I thought of launching the visualVM in Administrator mode,It resolved the issue.

Thanks @Lorenzo for inputs.